# How can I use stanford parser in my java program for effective sentiment analysis

Tags: parsing, machine-learning, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have to develop a project in java that uses a Stanford parser.What is the effective way to make use of Stanford Parser for sentiment analysis.How it could be  integrated with some machine learning algorithm to improve the accuracy of the sentiment predicted.? I have to get the sentiment in scale of 0 to 5  (very negative,negative...very positive).

Comment: Is there no manual for the Stanford Parser? What's the problem?

Comment: Here is some info for the Stanford sentiment analysis code: http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/code.html